# Multiple share buttons with different articles on one page

Tags: facebook, wordpress, share

Would it be possible to add multiple facebook and twitter buttons to one page, containing different articles. So if someone clicks on a share button next to an article, it takes that content and not the content of the full page?

Example: http://www.sporza.be/cm/sporza/voetbal/Rode_Duivels/SL_Rode_Duivels_WK?eid=1.1986352

Comment: This is possible if the different articles are coming from a loop

Comment: They are coming from a loop

Comment: here's a very detailed answer - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/33837/34509